# Wordpress Server Time not changing/displaying correctly

Tags: shortcode, date-time

I've diagnosed this as more a problem with the server than with wordpress itself (most likely)

Basically, the day of the week is always tuesday, and the time is always 12:00 when I try to display it using built-in wordpress functions (the_weekday(), etc.)

I'm trying to create a function using the weekday, but because of this issue, I've been unable to. The reason this is confusing me is that I have an events plugin that works flawlessly, so at least somehow my server is getting the correct time, but I've been unable to lock down how the events plugin is determining the date/time, so that I can translate that into the shortcode I am trying to create to no avail.

Comment: `the_weekday` outputs the day of the week the current post in the loop was posted on, it is not for fetching the current day of the week. Please add the code you are using to your question.

Comment: Are you trying to get the current time & day, or get those values from a time stamp you are passing?